# Discord.py, member.status showing allways offline

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots

```
> @bot.tree.command(name="user", description="Shows some informations about the mentioned user.")
async def user(interaction: discord.Interaction, member:discord.Member=None):
if member == None:
member = interaction.user
roles = [role for role in member.roles if role.name != "@everyone"]
embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Details about the user, {member.name}",color=0xdaddd8, timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow())
embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar) # Avatar Thumbnail
embed.add_field(name=" Name", value = f"{member.name}#{member.discriminator}") # Embeds
embed.add_field(name="️ Nickname", value = member.display_name)
embed.add_field(name=" User ID", value = member.id)
embed.add_field(name=" Created at", value = member.created_at.strftime("%D \n%I:%M %p"))
embed.add_field(name=" Joined at", value = member.joined_at.strftime("%D \n%I:%M %p"))
embed.add_field(name=" Status", value = member.status) #this line is'nt working as it should
embed.add_field(name="❤️‍ Top role", value = member.top_role.mention)
bot_status = "Yes, it is" if member.bot else "No, They'snt"
embed.add_field(name=" Bot?", value = bot_status)
embed.set_footer(text = interaction.user.name,icon_url = interaction.user.avatar)
await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)
```

I made a User information command and this command shows every person offline even itself how can i fix it?